# Forma correta de restringir uma classe T de uma função 'template <class T>' à um tipo que contenha determinado método

Tags: c++

Estou enviando aqui esta dúvida pois após procurar de diversas formas diferentes, não achei uma resposta direta. Desconfio que pelo fato da solução ser bastante simples, mas eu gostaria de vir à comunidade para confirmar.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de Computação Gráfica para o meu TCC, e gostaria de utilizar os conceitos de template de C++ para evitar utilizar funções virtuais e herança de classes em excesso. (A idéia do projeto é justamente comparar esta implementação de templates com uma que usa puramente herança de classes e funções virtuais).

Para isto, eu gostaria de implementar um método genérico que recebe um objeto para testar sua intersecção com um raio (um segmento de reta, mais especificamente), porém restringe o desenvolvedor que está usando a API à passar objetos que contenham o método `HitInfo Intersect()`, por exemplo. (HitInfo contém diz se o objeto é intersectado pelo raio, e se sim, guarda outras informações como a normal da superfície, etc...).

Nos meus testes, eu vi que se eu faço isto:

```
template<class T>
std::string example(T v1)
{
    return v1.to_viking();
}

class Foo { int v };

void main()
{
    Foo v;
    example(v);
}
```

O compilador retorna o seguinte erro:

```
error C2039: ' to_viking': não é um membro de 'Foo'
```

Ou seja, é basicamente o que eu estou pedindo.

Portanto, a minha pergunta é: há alguma forma mais recomendada ou até mais correta para se fazer isto? Sei que C++ 17 e C++ 20 trouxeram vários conceitos de constraints e concepts, mas não achei algo que pudesse me ajudar neste caso específico lendo sobre constraints e concepts em *cppreference.com*, porém ainda sou muito iniciante com C++ moderno e portanto algumas explicações fogem um pouco ao meu entendimento.

Desde já agradeço a atenção e a ajuda de quem puder ajudar.
Abraços.

Comment: leia mais sobre `concept` e em especial a cláusula `requires`, que deve expressar o que você quer.

Comment: @arfneto Obrigado! 
Eu já havia pesquisado sobre `concepts`, como disse na postagem original, porém não havia entendido a cláusula `requires`. 
Após sua mensagem, que confirmou que era isso que eu buscava, decidi ir mais a fundo e pesquisar exemplos mais claros de uso, o que ajudou bastante.